# Split the string with comma to the newline

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to split the string with a comma to a newline. I have tried using split and join function. It is removing commas only but not printing on a new line.

```
string='Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum'
```

My code is printing like this in HTML:

```
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
```

It's supposed to print like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
```

Code:

```js
{
  'date':'Nov 12',
  'name':"Agra",
  'entities': 14,
  'details':'Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum'
}

getdetails(x:any){
  this.detail = x.details;
  this.s = this.detail.split(',').join('\n')
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 overflow-auto test">
      <div class="alert alert-dark">No description yet <span class="font-weight-bold">+Add Description</span> </div>
      <p>{{s}}</p>

    </div
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7l88wv)

Comment: try to have like this instead, `this.s = this.detail.split(',').join('<br />')` if thats what you mean since this is HTML not a normal text.

Comment: Why not put each part of the split in a separate `<p>`? Note that for a newline in HTML you need `<br>` not `\n`.

Comment: <br> printing like this Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split the string - you have an array of the component parts of the string - simply iterate over these with an ngFor and use a block level element like a `p` element to automatically puth them on separate lines (or use a ul with the details in li's which again are block level elements and will render on new lines).

```
getdetails(x:any){
this.detail = x.details;
this.s = this.detail.split(','); // creates an array you can iterate over 
}

<p *ngFor="let _s of s">{{ _s }}</p>
```

Comment: Error; Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: sorry - that might be me messing with your structures in the snippet - solution edited. i personally would do it the original way i did it - but it also needs to fit your data structure and typescript definitions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display new line in template you can use `<br>` tag for new line.
And in html file use `innerHtml` property for binding data for p tag

Try this

.ts

```
this.s = this.detail.split(',').join('<br />')
```

.html

```
<p [innerHtml]="s"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You try:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">{{s}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.s = this.detail.split(',');`
and in the template
`<p *ngFor="let _s of s">{{_s}}</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Use pre tag to defines preformatted text.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 overflow-auto test">
      <div class="alert alert-dark">No description yet <span class="font-weight-bold">+Add Description</span> </div>
      <p>{{s}}</p>
  </div>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uflnbx)